# What's the difference between `BufWinEnter` and `BufEnter`?

Tags: buffers, autocmd, vim-windows

I need an example to differentiate the two events in Vim, as I'm having a hard time understanding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This difference is pretty obvious:

- `BufEnter X`:

1. It was `bufnr() != X`
2. But now it becomes `bufnr() == X`

- `BufWinEnter X`:

1. It was `len(win_findbuf(X)) == 0`
2. But now it becomes `len(win_findbuf(X)) == 1`

Comment: It's very clear now! I forgot the fact that a buffer in multiple windows! Thank you!

Comment: I would have written `empty(win_findbuf(X))`, but NBD.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble To me it rather clearly states "from zero to one". But de gustibus...

Comment: Good answers are always worth reviewing. I just forgot about their difference...